# How to keep deployment configuration out of deployed pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a project that only deploys one `pom.xml` to Maven Central.
It is intended to be used as a parent POM.
Therefore, the packaging is `pom`.

My problem arises because of the following overlap:

- The information which is to be deployed, i.e. the artiact contents, is fully contained inside the `pom.xml`.
- The additional information that Maven needs for proper deployment is **also** inside the `pom.xml`.

As a consequence, the deployment configuration gets deployed along with my parent POM.
Every project that uses my parent POM also by default will deploy to Maven Central when executing `mvn release`.
This is an unwanted side effect of the overlap described above.

I want to deploy the parent POM without the deployment information inside.
How can I do this?

(I strongly suspect that I can somehow separate the POM which is to be deployed from the POM that does the deploying, but I can't figure out how.)

The "deployment information" referred to above consists of:

- Build plugins (`/project/build/plugins/...`):

  - `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin`
  - `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin`
  - `org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin`
- Maven distributition management info (`/project/distributionManagement`)

Please also note that there are other build plugins configured which I actually *want* to deploy as part of the deployed POM.

[Here](https://github.com/jackadull/scala-parent/blob/c596818774ba201d156b3658f8c6b73460023a29/pom.xml) is a link to the `pom.xml` in the specific version that my question relates to.

This is a transcript of the file linked above, with everything that I actually *want* to deploy replaced with `<!-- ... -->`.
So this contains only the parts of the `pom.xml` that I do not want to be included in the deployed artifact:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- ... -->

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- ... -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.plugin.gpg}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.plugin.source}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- ... -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.plugin.nexus-staging}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
          <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- ... -->
  </build>

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I don't think that it can be done exactly in the way how I asked.
However, I found a feasible alternative that at least enables me to avoid my current problem.

I tried:

- using `<resources>` for removing `pom.xml` from the resources, and then adding a different `pom.xml`. This does not work, as apparently Maven always uses the main POM for deployment when specifying `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.
- making the module that I want to deploy a sub-module of an outer module. I put all the deployment-related configuration into the outer module. This does not work, as Maven expects the deployment configuration for every sub-module to be defined in that particular sub-module.

Here is the workaround that I found:

I put all the deployment-related configuration into a new profile in the same POM, which is not active by default.
Child modules will still inherit this profile.
But as it is not active by default, it does no harm unless activated explicitly.

In case anyone is interested, [here](https://github.com/jackadull/scala-parent/blob/d8d85a2507e85728b85179ffcdbb9d015d49cf9f/pom.xml) is the version after the change.
And [this](https://github.com/jackadull/scala-parent/commit/d8d85a2507e85728b85179ffcdbb9d015d49cf9f) is the particular commit where you can see the deployment configuration move down into the profiles section of the POM.